# Katalon : groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException : Using custom keyword in custom keyword

Tags: katalon-studio

In Katalon, if I want to use CustomKeyword inside another CustomKeyword. I getting `MissingPropertyException`

**Dialog Keywords**

```groovy
public class Dialog {

    @Keyword
    def clickCancel() {
      WebUI.click(findTestObject('Common/Components/Dialog/btn_Cancel'))
    }

    ...
}
```

**Root Navigation Keywords**

```groovy
public class RootNavigations {

    @Keyword
    def checkDialogWorking() {
      WebUI.click(findTestObject('App/Page_Home/btn_OpenComparisons_Dialog_Home'))
      CustomKeywords.'com.app.Dialog.clickCancel'()
    }

    ...
}
```

**Exception**

```
Test Cases/Smoke Test/Application/Check Dialog 
FAILED because (of) (Stack trace: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: 
No such property: CustomKeywords for class: com.app.RootNavigations
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import class into another Keyword class and declare its object to use that Keyword.

**Root Navigation Keywords**

```groovy
public class RootNavigations {

    final dialog = new Dialog() // ******* imp step

    @Keyword
    def checkDialogWorking() {
      WebUI.click(findTestObject('App/Page_Home/btn_OpenComparisons_Dialog_Home'))
      this.dialog.clickCancel() // ******* imp step
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to call custom keyword from another one you can call it also this way:

```
(new com.app.Dialog()).clickCancel()
```